# How to add a favicon into the actual address bar replacing the normal padlock?

Tags: browser, icons, favicon

I just noticed that the whatsapp web service in my Chrome browser (v85) is showing it's favicon not only in the top of the browser tab (as you'd expect) but also in the actual address bar, to the left of the web address where a padlock icon usually appears.

How is this done ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded that this was some kind of odd glitch. I can't now replicate what I saw myself in my own Chrome browser. For now this seems a bit of a mystery.

Comment: (Aside: if any of the other answers were helpful then you might consider awarding the bounty, since it just goes to waste otherwise - it is not refunded to you. However awarding a bounty is like voting generally - it is nice but not mandatory.)

Comment: Exactly.... not mandatory being the key point ;)

Comment: It wasn't my intention for it to be the key point, no. The key point I intended was that I normally encourage people here to be generous of spirit, and thus err on the side of giving a bounty, rather than letting the points evaporate. This is perhaps why I thought there was value in trimming the bounty commentary (effectively "I got there first, so sod you all"). However, the other answers aren't exactly exemplary, so I remain somewhat conflicted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: [https://smallbusiness.chron.com/display-website-logo-address-bar-favorites-list-47634.html#:~:text=Log%20in%20to%20your%20website's,and%20bookmarks%20for%20your%20website](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/display-website-logo-address-bar-favorites-list-47634.html#:%7E:text=Log%20in%20to%20your%20website%27s,and%20bookmarks%20for%20your%20website). It simply tells that you should put your favicon.ico to your root directory

I tried in my own website and it really works!

Comment: This is very general information about getting a fav icon to work and I can't replicate it working at all in the address bar.

Comment: Well try it in internet explorer. You will see your favicon in the address bar. I think chrome displays other icons when your website is not secure etc

Comment: But Im asking about chrome in a secured environment, ie in my example you see that it's whats app which is clearly https

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there isn't any specific way to accomplish this via your site's code. Instead, I think you are seeing the effects of Google's stated intention to move away from displaying the secure lock icon on pages using https, as this has become more of the majority on sites than non-secure pages.

More information: https://blog.chromium.org/2018/05/evolving-chromes-security-indicators.html

Comment: This information is very old (in browser revision terms) and isn't specific at all to what I've seen and posted this question about.